# Action bar button does have any restriction with android version

Tags: android, version

Actually I am using action bar button in my app. Its running good in jelly bean but causing problems with 2.3 version of android. It's crashing while running on 2.3 with there is nothing any problem related to jelly bean.
[image: this is my app pic]

Comment: Action bar first added in Android 3.0. So to make your app compatible with it. Use the Sherlock or Actionbar Compat Library. Post your logcat here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use actionbar sherlock library

http://actionbarsherlock.com/

https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock

Also see example . Now u have to extend SherlockActivity for Activity .

Comment: http://actionbarsherlock.com/..i used following link to download zip of it..put later on what i need to do..how can add it to my project

Comment: Import 1st one which is library .

Comment: @keshav.. just that much

Comment: Now u need to add this library to ur project. For this right click on project,go to property, go to android tab, click on add button in library section.Now use it .